# Google Cloud Build - multiple values in a single substitution?

Tags: bazel, google-cloud-build

I'm using Google Cloud Build and in one of its steps, I'm running a Bazel build. I'm trying to use substitutions to build multiple targets in one invocation.

When:

1. The step looks like:

```
{
      "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel",
      "args": [
        "build",
        "$_TARGETS",
      ]
}
```

2. The `TARGETS` substitution is `//foo/... //bar/...`

The command that is actually running is `bazel build "//foo/... //bar/..."` and that obviously results in an invalid target name error. (A single target works just fine)

The end result should be something like `bazel build //foo/... //bar/...`

Is there a way to "split" multiple arguments in a single sub? or make the command treat the arguments separately?

Comment: Let me reformulate: Do you want to split `$_TARGET` into an array to pass a list space separated values to Bazel and not only one value. Is that make sense?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I want to achieve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tough to a workaround. I tested with Bazel (not build, I don't have example with, but with help, version and other simple keyword. It seams working.

With Cloud Build you are able to execute linux command, even with specific Cloud Builder. Simply specify the `entrypoint`.

```
{
      "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel",
      "entrypoint": "bash",
      "args": [
        "-c",
        "bazel build $_TARGETS",
      ]
}
```

You should achieve what you want. If not try to update the `$_TARGET` by `$(echo $_TARGET)` to print the `$_TARGET` (and thus, to delete the quotes if still present)